# Connect to wifi using wifi-menu

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, raspberry-pi

I just got a Raspberry Pi (in a kit) and installed Arch Linux on it. I plugged in my WiFi dongle (which came in the kit) and I see that Linux has the driver for it.

However, I still cannot connect to my WiFi network. I used `wifi-menu` and I selected my network. I entered the password and hit enter. After a few seconds (~10), I got an error: `Connecting Failed! Do you want to save the profile "MyWifiNetwork"?`

Is there something else that I have to do?

Comment: You should post an actual cut n' paste transcript of the error (regarding "the 'job' cannot be completed").  Also, output from `iwconfig`.

Comment: @goldilocks see my edits...

Comment: What's the driver? What's the dongle? (you might not know, try `lspci | grep Network`). What authentication type is your network?

Comment: @Seth, my router is on WEP (since I need to support older devices) with Open (No Authentication), but has a Network Key

Comment: WEP is probably your problem - if you have an N dongle it will belly up every time.